# FOSUser : overriding registration view to avoid csrf and validation unappropriated error messages

Tags: forms, symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

I am trying to override my html twig view hoping it will solve a problem of validation messages.

html twig file:

```
    {% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

    {% block fos_user_content %}


   <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }}      method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">



 <div>
     <label for="fos_user_registration_form_username" class="required">Nom d&#039;utilisateur :</label>
     <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_username" name="fos_user_registration_form[username]" required="required" maxlength="255" pattern=".{2,}" />
 </div>

<div>
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_email" class="required">Adresse e-mail :</label>
    <input type="email" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" required="required" /></div>
<div>
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" class="required">Mot de passe :</label>
    <input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]" required="required" /></div>

<div>
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" class="required">Vérification :</label>
    <input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]" required="required" /></div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}"    />
</div>
  </form>
 {% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

The form displays correctly but does not submit.

Is the input name correct according the FOSUser bundle entity?
what is missing and what is wrong?
How to display error?
How to deal with the CSRF hidden field?

Comment: it is not saved in the database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem like this:

```
 <form action="/projet_etienne_auth/web/app_dev.php/register/"  method="POST"     class="fos_user_registration_register">
      {{ form_errors(form) }}
      {{ form_widget(form._token) }}


<div>
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_username" class="required">Nom d&#039;utilisateur :</label>

    <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_username" name="fos_user_registration_form[username]" required="required" maxlength="255" pattern=".{2,}" />
</div>

    <div>
        <label for="fos_user_registration_form_email" class="required">Adresse e-mail :</label>

        <input type="email" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" required="required" /></div>

    <div>
        <label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" class="required">Mot de passe :</label>

        <input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div><label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" class="required">Vérification :</label>
        <input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]" required="required" />
    </div>



<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
</div>
```

the  {{ form_widget(form) }} or  {{ form_rest(form) }} was generating unappropriate validation message or csrf_error.

hoping it can help someone out...